# How do I plot the rate of convergence of an iterative method?

Tags: matlab

I started to learn how to program in MatLab and I'm trying to get an idea of how fast Newton's Method converges. I currently want to plot the absolute error |xn−x| of the iterates xn, where x = sqrt(10) is the true solution. The error should go to zero, since the method does converge, but when I plot it no points appear. Can anyone help me figure out this issue?

```
f = @(x) (x).^2 - 10;
f_deriv = @(x) 2*x;
x0 = 1;
x_true = sqrt(10);
x_save = (x0);

for jj = 1:20
    plot(jj,abs(x_save(jj)-x_true),'k.');
    x_new = x0 - f(x0)/f_deriv(x0);
    x_save(1+jj,1) = x_new;
    x0 = x_new;
end

xlim([0 20]);
ylim([0 2.5]);
xticks(0:20);
yticks(0:0.1:2.5);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, the Newton's Method portion is working as intended. The problem is with your plotting portion.

In your implementation, you generate 1 plot per iteration in your for loop.
That results in 20 plots with 1 point per plot, which is not your desired result.

Below is code to generate 1 plot with 21 points.

```
f = @(x) (x).^2 - 10;
f_deriv = @(x) 2*x;
x0 = 1;
x_true = sqrt(10);
x_save = (x0);

for jj = 1:20
    % Don't plot here. Wait until all data is collected.
    x_new = x0 - f(x0)/f_deriv(x0);
    x_save(1+jj,1) = x_new;
    x0 = x_new;
end

% Plot here. All data has been collected.
plot(0:20',abs(x_save-x_true),'kx');
xlim([0 20]);
ylim([0 2.5]);
xticks(0:20);
yticks(0:0.1:2.5);
```

---

EDIT: To address the issue of missing points with `semilogy` instead of `plot`.

1. The points are missing because `semilogy` computes the log of the values. `log(0) = -Inf`
2. Machine precision causes very small numbers to be treated as zero.
3. The precision of floating point subtraction is proportional to the magnitude of the inputs. Subtracting two large numbers has low precision.

Below is an example of changing co-ordinates to avoid the subtraction of two large numbers.

```
% Original problem parameters
x0 = 1;
x_true = sqrt(10);

% Change of co-ordinates
% u = x - sqrt(10);
% f(x) = g(u(x))
g = @(u) u^2 + 2*x_true*u;
g_deriv = @(u) 2*u + 2*x_true;
u0 = x0 - x_true;
u_save = u0;

for jj = 1:20
    u_new = u0 - g(u0)/g_deriv(u0);
    u_save = [u_save u_new];
    u0 = u_new;
end

semilogy(0:20, abs(u_save - 0), 'kx')
xlim([0 20]);
```

You will notice that the points beyond 6 iterations still disappears because the error is still less than machine precision (~1e-15). However, the error does not increase again.

If you want to increase the precision of your calculations, you may want to look into the `vpa` function.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/increase-precision-of-numeric-calculations.html

Comment: When I use semilogy instead of plot and change the y-axis scale to logarithmic some of the points don't appear even though it does when plot is used. Is there something I need to add to make it appear or is it just the imprecise nature of matlab? The only change I made was replacing plot with semilogy.

Comment: @ArataKaizaki I'm able to replicate your issue. It looks like the error drops below machine precision after 6 iterations. Once the error is treated as 0, the semilogy is unable to plot that point (log(0) = -Inf). However, the way your error function is defined involves subtracting two "large" numbers (compared to your error). As a result, the error does not remain zero. I will edit my post to include a technique to bypass the subtraction of two large numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You only need `hold on` so that each plot is *added* to the previous ones. By default each new plot *replaces* the previous one.

In addition, I have modified the marker from `'.'` to `'o'` for better visibility.

You may also want to include `drawnow` (and perhaps a suitable `pause`) after each `plot` so that the figure is immediately updated. This is useful if you want to see the line depicted by the markers "grow".

```
f = @(x) (x).^2 - 10;
f_deriv = @(x) 2*x;
x0 = 1;
x_true = sqrt(10);
x_save = (x0);

hold on %%% New line
for jj = 1:20
    plot(jj,abs(x_save(jj)-x_true),'ko'); %%% Modified line
    x_new = x0 - f(x0)/f_deriv(x0);
    x_save(1+jj,1) = x_new;
    x0 = x_new;
end

xlim([0 20]);
ylim([0 2.5]);
xticks(0:20);
yticks(0:0.1:2.5);
```